# How to store structs in a file to easily reload?

Tags: c++, file-io

I've got these two structs that I need to store in files. I can't find a good way to get them into a file without parsing the struct and writing it as a text file, which is far less efficient than I'd like. What is the simplest way to get a struct of mostly primitives into a file? The structs are below

```
struct object
{
    unsigned short id;
    float x;
    float y;
    unsigned short type;
    unsigned char flags;
};

struct sector
{
    unsigned long id;
    unsigned long neighbors[4]; // North,East,South,West
    std::vector<object> objects;
};
```

I've tried the code below to write the struct to a file, but it doesn't work very well. The size of the file after execution is only 4.7kb, while it should be much larger than that.

```
sector s;
object o;
s.id = 1;
s.neighbors = {2, 3, 4, 5};
o.id = 1; o.x = 2.0f; o.y = 3.0f; o.type = 4; o.flags = 6;
for(int i = 0; i < 65536; i++)
{
    s.objects.push_back(o);
    o.id += 1; o.x += 1.0f; o.y += 1.0f; o.type += 1; o.flags += 1;
}

ofstream os("world.dat", ios::binary|ios::out);
s.objects.resize(s.objects.size());
int size = s.objects.size() * sizeof(object);
os.write((char*)&size, sizeof(int));
os.write((char*)&s, size);
os.close();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try outputting saving the memory to disk directly ? For example, `memcpy` from `&o` to a `byte` array, and save it as binary data to the disk

Comment: So what if it's only 4.7kb? Have you tried reading it back in from disk to see if it is valid? If it is, you're set.

Comment: @Itsik that's essentially what he's doing without copying data to a diff location in memory first.

Comment: Run it through zlib before saving so it can be even smaller!

Comment: @OJ, Before I created the sector class, I used similar code to write a vector of 65536 instances of the object struct to a file, it was 1MB in size. Adding additional attributes shouldn't decrease its size should it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write a struct containing a vector using raw byte I/O. The vector class is a small data structure that stores its data somewhere on the heap, not in the struct. This is because it is impossible for a struct to "know," ahead of time, how many objects it will hold.

You can write the contents of the vector thus:

```
os.write((const char*)&s.id, sizeof(s.id));
os.write((const char*)&s.neighbors, sizeof(s.neighbors));
os.write((const char*)&s.objects[0], size);
```

As to why the file ends up with only 4.7 kB in it, I don't know. Print out `size` to see how much data is being written. I checked the code after the above changes, and it works.

Also, you don't need `s.objects.resize(s.objects.size());`. Resizing the vector to its own size is redundant.

Also note a small quirk. sizeof(object) == 16 on my architecture, which is more than required for the above struct (2 + 4 + 4 + 2 + 1 == 13). The compiler usually adds padding to ensure that primitives of size 2<sup>*n*</sup> are aligned to a 2<sup>*n*</sup>-byte boundary, which results in holes inside each struct and between structs in the vector.

The consequence of this is that you are writing extra bytes to the file, some of which are random noise. In non-debug builds, those holes are never filled with anything, so they just contain whatever rubbish was at that memory location before it was allocated for your purposes. Therefore, if you run the program twice, it is possible that the two files will not be identical.

Comment: So I either need to get the data out of the vector into the file separately or find another way of storing the objects within that struct.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you could use a serialization library such as [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). This has support for STL containers out of the box and so it should be very simple to support the structs in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just figured out a solution. The number of objects is a constant, so using a vector is unnecessary. I replaced the `vector<object> objects` with `object objects[256][256]`, which is written to a file correctly with my current code. I've also abandoned keeping track of the position of one sector relative to another by id's and neighboring id's in favor of an x,y coordinate system. Should be easier to keep track of. I wish I knew why I always overcomplicate things then simplify them..

```
struct object
{
    unsigned short id;
    float x;
    float y;
    unsigned short type;
    unsigned char flags;
};
struct sector
{
    unsigned long x;
    unsigned long y;
    object objects[256][256];
};
sector s;
object o;

s.x = 1; s.y = 1;
o.id = 1; o.x = 2.0f; o.y = 3.0f; o.type = 4; o.flags = 6;
for(int x = 0; x < 256; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < 256; y++)
    {
        s.objects[x][y] = o;
        o.id += 1; o.x += 1.0f; o.y += 1.0f; o.type += 1; o.flags += 1;
    }
}

ofstream os("world.dat", ios::binary|ios::out);
int size = sizeof(sector);
os.write((char*)&s, size);
os.close();
```

This is working correctly. I guess what I'm doing is building a 2d map, each node containing its own 2d map. Perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: Yes, that should work. Note the small caveat in my latest answer, though.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos, I knew that it padded the the output, but I thought it used zeroes. Something else to work out now.. yay!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `fread()` and `fwrite()`? If you don't need human-readablity for the file,  and object and sector are both PODs, then this sort of thing should work for you:

```
object o;
FILE * fh = ...;
...
fwrite( &o, sizeof(o), 1, fh );

fread( &o, sizeof(o), 1, fh );
```

Normally I wouldn't recommend this sort of C oriented coding, but sometimes the old ways are still the simplest.

Note that this code requires the array of sector in object to be of constant size.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know why only 4.7K is being stored in the file, you'll need to say which OS you're using and which C++ compiler. Since 's' is on the stack, it would be a reasonable assumption that only 4.7K of the stack was being used when you chose to write '&s' to file. On Windows, the environment block occupies 3.8K of stack space. Therefore, on Windows, your application used an additional 0.9K of stack space (after the environment block) at the point at which you chose to invoke the write() on '&s', and because the stack grows downwards, the C++ implementation chose to only honour (silently) the write() up to the point where the stack begins, i.e. 4.7K above '&s'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using libraries, then your structure should be POD. Then you can store whole structure in a binary file. Otherwise you might get data allocated on a heap.